# ipv6 firewall required?

Tags: firewall, ipv6

I just noticed my VPS has a pingable IPv6 address but I only use IPv4 and I as such I did not think to install an IPv6 firewall. I have only IPv4 iptables rules. Does this mean that my machine is completely open through IPv6!?

Comment: It depends on how you set up the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that my machine is completely open through IPv6!?

Yes. Definitely add rules for IPv6 already!

Of course it could be that only SSH is listening or services that are supposed to be public anyways so a firewall would just be insurance against future changes to the configuration.

Comment: Great. So I have to implement 2 firewalls and keep them synced? How do people do this in practice? Just brute force or is there a procedure or tool for generating parallel rules?

Comment: `for j in ""{,6}; do ip"$j"tables ...; done`